# assertTrue with "instanceof" vs assertEquals

Tags: java, junit

I wonder why this fails:

```
assertEquals(Key.class, expectedKey.getClass());
```

and this does not:

```
assertTrue(expectedKey instanceof Key);
```

Is there a real difference between the two?

Comment: You may use Key.class.isInstance(expectedKey)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `expectedKey` is an instance of a *subclass* of Key, most probably. The error message you get from the failed assertion should tell you. Read it.

`"s"`, for example is an instance of java.lang.Object, but its class is not java.lang.Object, it's java.lang.String.

Answer (score 5):

Because `expectedKey.getClass()` gives the `Class` object of runtime type of the `expectedKey`, which may be different from `Key` class.

However, with `instanceof`, even if `expectedKey` runtime type is some subclass of `Key` class, the result will be `true`, because an instance of subclass, is also an `instanceof` the super class.

Answer (score 2):

`expectedKey` is a subclass of `Key` class as i can see

`assertTrue(expectedKey instanceof Key)` returning true since expectedKey's class is a subclass of Key class

`Object.getClass` returns the complete class name of that object at run time and hence `expectedKey.getClass` outputs ->`ExpectedClass` and `Key.getClass` outputs `Key class itself` 
and 
`assertEquals` looks for comparison becomes in your case as below
`assertEquals(Key,ExpectedKey)` and both are different

hence it returns false

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference in handling `null`, too. The `assertEquals` throws a `NullPointerExeption` whereas the `assertTrue` simply fails.